# Implicit type of constant in swift tutorial

Tags: swift, constant-expression

When I do example from tutorial, I get some issue from constants variables topic.

If someone explain my example I'll be appreciate for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify a type, a floating point number literal will be inferred to be of type `Double`.

`Double`, as its name suggests, has double precision than `Float`. So when you do:

```
let a = 64.1
```

The actual value in memory may be something like 64.099999999999991. Since `Double` shows only 16 significant digits, it shows 64.09999999999999, rounding off the last "1".

Why does `let b: Float = 64.1` show the correct number?

When you specify the type to float, the precision decreases. `Float` only shows 8 significant digits. That's 64.099999, but there's a "9" straight after that, so it rounds it up to get 64.1.

This has nothing to do with explicitly stating the variable type. Try specifying it to be a `Double`:

```
let b: Double = 64.1
```

It will still show 64.09999999999999.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand why not round numbers less than 64. What's the difference between 64 and 63? Is it about round ?

Comment: Floating point numbers are really unpredictable. It just so happens to be that 64.1 is stored in memory as 64.09999999999999xxxx... where the "x"s are unknown. @KorayYavic